# mapbox-gl-js won't render when bundled with browserify

Tags: javascript, cordova, browserify, mapbox-gl-js

I have an odd issue with mapbox-gl-js. When I add the mapbox-gl.js file as CDN to html doc head, the map renders fine. When I require it and bundle it with browserify as documented, the map doesn't render and I get a bundling error like this: `Error: Cannot find module './feature' from '/home/.../mbtst/node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist'`

The docs describe how to use a module bundler:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/.
At the time of posting this issue that was (it has since been changed due to this issue):

```
npm install --save mapbox-gl
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl';
// or "const mapboxgl = require('mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl');"
```

My map is initiated like this:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZWxsdnRyemVnIiwiYSI6ImNpejl4M2M0NDAxbWoycXRlanZnc283dnYifQ.sPFCSTsdlCOp1hk6afDvJg';
this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map-container', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', 
    center: [6.16342, 62.47126], // aalesund 
    zoom: 11
});
```

If I just require the module as such `require('mapbox-gl');` - same error.

I even tried to save the file from the CDN source and require that file - which complains about multiple dependency modules missing.

The code is in this repo:
https://github.com/awesomemaptools/mbtst

PS: I need to bundle the script for offline use in a Cordova app, ie using cdn is not an option.

Comment: Now reported as bug to mapbox: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/4453

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that it is a bug and the folks at mapbox are working to fix it, see issue here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/4453

Meanwhile I upgraded from mapbox-gl version "^0.33.1" to "^0.34.0" and now it works with a workaround when including src instead of dist like this:

```
const mapboxgl = require('mapbox-gl/src/index.js');
```

I tried that with the previous version but it didn't work then.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided seems basically OK. Try to use `require` instead of `import`:

```
const mapboxgl = require('mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl');
```

Then call the following in the terminal:

```
browserify your-main-js-file.js > bundle.js
```

This adds your code and the required modules to the created JavaScript file `bundle.js`, so everything should be available even if your're offline.

Afterwards add the output bundle to your HTML page via script-tag:

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

See https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#bundling-for-the-browser for a bit more details and check the [options](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage) browserify takes to customize your bundle.

Comment: Thanks, I don't actually have any difficulties using browserify, I've been using that on several projects; on this project for ~3 weeks; it works great with leaflet and a bunch of other dependencies. mapboxgl.Map is instantiated and logged to browser console; yet nothing renders. The gitlab repo is now public (temporarily); you can clone it and run it in a browser with gulp.

Comment: Hi and thanks for providing your code in a public repo. Unfortunately I cannot build the branch 'mapbox-gl'. It comes to errors when running `gulp build:js`: `Error: Cannot find module 'lodash._baseisequal' from '/my/path/mbglcrd/node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist`

Comment: I will try later on in a clean environment. Could it be the errors of including the mapbox-gl module that I talk about? Try to comment out the module require, it should work. I improved a few things in repo btw.

Comment: I created a super simple test repo instead which highlight the same problem: https://github.com/awesomemaptools/mbtst - ie the problem seems to be general, not just in my app.